# How can I debug a WCF client using username/password in the header encrypted with SSL

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm still trying to get WCF to talk to CXF.  I used a sample from http://rocksolidknowledge.com/Download.mvc and it looks to me like the code works because when I change the username in the client, I see the new username in the service.

I tried to add logging in the client app.config to save what is being sent to the service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
              <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Av1Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                  openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                  allowCookies="false">

                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />

                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>

                <!--
                <security mode="None">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                      realm="" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                      algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                </security>
                -->
              </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>

          <behavior name="client">
            <clientCredentials>
              <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
        <client>

            <endpoint address="https://darsdevlaptop:8015/DarsWebServices/services/av1" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Av1Service" contract="Av1ServiceReference.Av1Service"
                name="WSHttpBinding_Av1Service" />

          <!--
            <endpoint 
              address="http://localhost:9015/DarsWebServices/services/av1" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Av1Service" contract="Av1ServiceReference.Av1Service"
                name="WSHttpBinding_Av1Service" />
          -->
        </client>
      <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                        logMalformedMessages="true"
                        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                        maxMessagesToLog="3000"
                        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
      </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This configuration makes a client_msg.svclog file which I can view with the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer.  And inside this file I see

```
E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-08T15:27:46.1360000Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="Clieint.vshost" ProcessID="5660" ThreadID="10" />
<Channel />
<Computer>DARSDEVLAPTOP</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2011-12-08T10:27:46.1320000-05:00" Source="ServiceLevelSendRequest" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<HttpRequest>
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData>uIDPo7bjbPmwsKdKqJIT7OFhvN8AAAAA+hhv3g5Q+UymaaUAoh1MoXMwGPaCPSlAoTQw7kFj3m8ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IPing/Ping</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:85d46f93-9798-41c4-a8fd-e862b3858d46</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<Ping xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></Ping>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

And I am dismayed not to find any reference to username or password

```
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IPing/Ping</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:85d46f93-9798-41c4-a8fd-e862b3858d46</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
</s:Header>
```

I also tried running fiddler2, but I'm not seeing any username/password there either.
So what is happening?  Am I missing how to use the view tools? Is it being passed not in the header? If so, how would I fix that!

Just to explain why I care about this:

- I gave code based on the sample to my customer to talk to the CXF
  service and the report I'm getting back is that the username/password
  is not being passed.
- I can't actually debug the communication myself because I can't seem
  to get WCF to take the test certificate from CXF.
- Everything worked fine WCF to WCF but that isn't what the customer
  needs.

I'm feeling very stumped.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the diagnostic source being set. Such as this.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
                 <add name="messages"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
          </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I hope you have looked at this [msdn article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.  Now I'm seeing <o:Username><!-- Removed --></o:Username><o:Password><!-- Removed --></o:Password> So I'm closer but I still can't prove that the username and password are being sent.

Comment: If you see username password being passed in the logs. Your client side is good. Nothing can be proved any further for client side. Time to look at server :) Do you have control over it.

Comment: I don't see the username and password because I get <-- Removed --> instead.  But based on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/9b4d8f5c-bdb6-45f0-be5e-e014cccab831, maybe this is the best I can do.